# LINUX SYN_RECV SOCKETS

Tags: linux

Please help me to resolve the issue I am facing in my Linux Server.

I have a Linux System having 16GB RAM. 
My java server is running on this machine it accepts only tcp connections from its clients.
But there are alsways 8 -10 clients stay in TCP DISCONNECTION state.
When I have checked my linux system by running 
netstat -an | grep -c SYN
it gives always a value between 4 to 10 or sometimes more than 10.
CAN any one help to get rid of it.
how can I have 0 SYN_RECV sockets.
Thank you in advance.

sysct.conf is as follows:-

1. net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
2. net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
3. net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
4. kernel.sysrq = 0
5. kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
6. net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
7. kernel.msgmnb =    65536
8. kernel.msgmax = 65536
9. kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
10. kernel.shmall = 4294967296
11. net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
12. net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
13. net.core.wmem_max =    16777216
14. net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
15. net.core.netdev_max_backlog =    30000
16. net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
17. net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 1
18. net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
19. net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
20. net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
21. net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
22. net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = htcp
23. net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
24. net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0
25. net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
26. net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 0
27. net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 0
28. fs.file-max = 4573502
29. net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1000000

Comment: I think this means that connections are being received faster than your server can `accept()` them. Is it processing all connections in one process or thread, or does it spawn worker threads/processes to handle each connection in parallel?

Comment: Yes all connections are getting handled in parallel by spawning new threads for every new connection. Sir, it possible to make SYN_RECV sockets to 0 by changing LINUX network tuning parameters
??? if we can ,Please help if you are aware with those parameters.

Comment: my /etc/sysctl.conf file is as follows